# Change only one field of model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app I have a model called application ins this model I have a field called status, this is my model

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :job
    belongs_to :user

    scope :new, where(:status => 'New')
    scope :reviewed, where(:status => 'Profile Reviewed')
    scope :offered, where(:status => 'Offer Given')
    scope :accepted, where(:status => 'Offer Accepted')
    scope :hired, where(:status => 'Hired')
    scope :declined, where(:status => 'Decline')
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to change only the status in an modal (all status with checkbox) in the application show page if so what is the best ways to do it, or the status must be a separated model

Comment: Having a `status` column with English labels is usually a sign you haven't quite denormalized your data enough. It's better to use a code, like `offer_given`, or a lookup table value for data consistency purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `update` method in a controller is not obligated to change all fields. It can apply a singular change if that's all you need. It really depends on the parameters passed in. You can even make a status change method that toggles only one thing:

```
 def change_status
   @application.status = params[:status]
   @application.save!
 end
```

Keep in mind when dealing with drop-down values like this you'll want to have validation on your model to reject invalid selections.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for, and yes I have a validation of status and I'm thinking to use checkbox in an modal instead of select do you think it is a good solution?

Comment: How you trigger the change is entirely up to you, and a checkbox could do the job.

Comment: Ok think you for your help